# location of lombok.config file in java project

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

`@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)` shows following error in eclipse  :

> This deprecated feature is no longer supported. Remove it; you can
>   create a lombok.config file with
>   'lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true'.

I created this file , but the errors are not going away after commenting the @AllArgsConstructor line.

Can somebody please help on where to place this file exactly - I tried keeping in project root as well as src folder, but it did not work even after cleaning the project in eclipse? Do we need to do any specific action for the changes in lombok.config to reflect, like we have to restart eclipse after installing lombok.

I am using lombok version `1.16.18` , tried `1.14.4` version also, but same issue.

Comment: You need to "clean all" and recompile; Eclipse restart is irrelevant .

Comment: that does not help; by restart I meant just like after installing lombok we should restart eclipse, similarly do we need to do anything after placing this config file.

Comment: Does it need to be under BOTH `src/main/resources`  AND also `src/test/resources`   or just under `src/main/resources` ?

Answer (score 23):

The [lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) is a little hazy on the location of `lombok.config` and it states

> Usually, a user of lombok puts a lombok.config file with their preferences in a workspace or project root directory

I misunderstood this to mean the project root when it's actually the sources root. If using Maven or Gradle, you can put the file in `src/main/java/lombok.config`. You can reduce the packages for which the config applies by putting `lombok.config` in the package directory (eg `src/main/java/com/foo/mypackage/lombok.config`). Using the second approach it's possible to have different config for different packages

Comment: I put `lombok.config` in the project root directory of my Spring Boot project and it works fine.

Comment: I put the file under `src/main/java`; that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

According to [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) You can create `lombok.config` files in any directory and put configuration directives in it.
 These apply to all source files in this directory and all child directories.

So if you want to affect all your code put the `lombok.config` in your root directory.

In your `lombok.config` file specify

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties=true
```

> If true, lombok will not generate a
>   `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties` annotation when generating
>   constructors. This is particularly useful for GWT and Android
>   development.

And in your class just use `@AllArgsConstructor` in that way  :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Simple {
    private String text;
    private int num;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ; I had already seen that page, & kept the config file at multiple places, which was not working because I misunderstood the deprecation is  referring to the annotation(@AllArgsConstructor) itself, rather than its attribute, so was commenting out the entire annotation as mentioned in the question

Comment: So it helped you?

Comment: Cant say for sure now , but , how to figure out whether the config file is actually working- because after removing (suppressConstructorProperties = true) from the annotation , this particular error is gone, but there is no error in any other file irrespective of whether I have lombok.config file there or not in my root directory, which was coming as a result of commenting the whole annotation earlier.

Comment: I know, I wrote you can do in the config file, what you tried to do in the annotation